# Android Listview text colour white onCreateView(instead of black)

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Attached are 2 photos one when the list is populated using the onCreateView when the app starts(white text) and the other is whenever the SetList() method is called

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHNEL.png

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,((MainActivity)getActivity()).Logs);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uTe1.png

```
    public void SetList()
{
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Logs);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved by changing 
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,((MainActivity)getActivity()).Logs);`

to

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,((MainActivity)getActivity()).Logs);`

it seems like for some reason `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext()` returns a different default text color than `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getBaseContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,((MainActivity)getActivity()).Logs);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,((MainActivity)getActivity()).Logs);
```

in `onCreateView`. The problem is that you are using 2 different layouts in the adapter. Using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` should give you `TextView` with black text the first time too.

Comment: It was already that I seemed to have copied a version that I was trying fixes on OP edited to reflect this

Comment: Did you try to run after setting both adapter to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`?

Comment: I did same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try this, Override getView method and set text color like this

```
 countryadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateGroupsActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            CommonListClass.countryName) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_color));
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_color));
            return v;
        }
    };
```